# All possible set of digits that sum==n in python list

Tags: python, list

I want do do some changes on a list depending by n. For example:

l=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]   n=4  :

```
 print   l   #first iteration will print :[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]    # 4=1+1+1+1
 print   l   #next iteration will print :[1,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]    # 4=1+1+2
 print   l   #next iteration will print :[0,2,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]    # 4=2+2
 print   l   #next iteration will print :[1,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]    # 4=1+3
 print   l   #last iteration will print :[0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]    # 4=4
```

**sequence in list doesnt'matter for me**, but element must aways  be =>9
**Should be every possible set of digits that sum==n.Rest filled with zeros**

Comment: the question is very unclear, why do you have multiple lists in each example? what is the logic behind those numbers?

Comment: what if n > len(l)? Error?

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind the numbering, either. Also, you probably want a list of lists rather than reassigning `l` repeatedly.

Comment: n will be not greater than len(l)

Comment: if the list is filled with zeros at the start, in what way do you populate it?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?  a function to transform from one stage to the next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
n = 11

for i in range (0,n):
        l[i] = 1 

print l
carryidx = 0 
for i in reversed(range(0,n - 1)):
        v = l[ n - 1] + l[i]
        if v > 9:
                while l[carryidx] > 9:
                        carryidx += 1
                l[carryidx] += 1
        else:
                l[n - 1] = v 
        l[i] = l[i] - 1 
        print l
```

**Output**

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: almost ok, sry i will edit question

Comment: why isn't [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] there?

Comment: @gnibbler, this answers an older, unclear version of the question